# File name as current time in seconds since the epoch in c++

Tags: c++

I want to create a new file in c++ having file name as seconds (current time in seconds since the epoch) in FILE_FOLDER.

How can I modify the statement

```
myfile.open("/FILE_FOLDER/seconds");
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the seconds since the epoch as a string is fairly easy:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
auto now_sec_str = std::to_string(now_sec.count());
```

Or simply:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

auto now_sec_str = std::to_string(long(std::time(nullptr)));
```

Then just append that to your folder name:

```
myfile.open("/FILE_FOLDER/" + now_sec_str);
```

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear as I am not an expert of programming. The problem is, appending that time and including it in the above statement.

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to do `"/FILE_FOLDER/" + now_sec_str` but I've updated the answer with that information anyway.